# docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: docker, devops, docker-image

I trying on Ubuntu 18.04, Trying to run a docker example Following this documentation: 
https://www.learnitguide.net/2018/06/write-dockerfile-to-build-own-images.html

```
docker run -d -it --name myweb80012 -p 192.168.2.1:8001:8001 myserver_new
```

But i am getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint myweb80012 (94a73a664dd3b9c9dc59b750e70d157568f4d4551f733c29d5f86c7e0db287b8): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.2.1:8001: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

my docker version

```
  # docker -v
    Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4

 #sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:49:01 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       4d60db4
  Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:16:44 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind to an ip address that doesn't exist on any interface on your host. Either remove the ip addresses from the port publish or use one that exists on your host:

```
docker run -d -it --name myweb80012 -p 8001:8001 myserver_new
```

or for something like loopback:

```
docker run -d -it --name myweb80012 -p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 myserver_new
```